# Problema na lista

Tags: c, lista

A lista deveria inserir os campos da struct caminhoes e depois imprimir-los.Mas quando peço para imprimir,só aparece a primeira inserção.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct caminhoes{
    int id;
    char motorista[200];
    char marca[200];
    char la[200];
    char lisd[200];
    float kml;
    struct caminhoes *prox;
}lcam;

typedef struct cargas{
    int id;
    char produto[200];
    char origem[200];
    char destino[200];
    float vfrete;
    struct cargas *prox;
}lcar;

 typedef struct cidades{
    int id;
    char nome[200];
    char vizinhos[200];
    float distancia;
    float vc;
    struct cidades *prox;
}lcid;


void cad_cam(lcam **cabeca);
void cad_car(lcar **cabeca);
void cad_cid(lcid **cabeca);
void imp_cam(lcam *cabeca);
void imp_car(lcam *cabeca);
void imp_cid(lcam *cabeca);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    lcam *cabeca = NULL;        
    lcam *noatual;     

    int op;

    printf("0 - Fechar \n");
    printf("1 - Cadastrar Caminhão \n");
    printf("2 - Cadastrar Carga \n");
    printf("3 - Cadastrar Cidade \n");
    printf("4 - Imprimir \n" );
    printf("5 - Excluir \n");
    printf("6 - Salvar Arquivo \n");
    printf("6 - Relatórios \n");

    printf("Digite uma opcao: \n");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    while(op!=0){
    switch(op){
            case 0:{
                op=0;
                break;
             }
             break;
            case 1: cad_cam(&cabeca);
                    break;
            case 2: ;
                    break;
            case 3: 
                    break;  
            case 4: imp_cam(cabeca);
                    break;
            case 5:         
                    break;
            case 6:
                   break;
        }
    printf("0 - Fechar \n");
    printf("1 - Cadastrar Caminhão \n");
    printf("2 - Cadastrar Carga \n");
    printf("3 - Cadastrar Cidade \n");
    printf("4 - Imprimir \n" );
    printf("5 - Excluir \n");
    printf("6 - Relatórios \n");

    printf("Digite uma opcao: \n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    } 
}


void imp_cam(lcam *noatual)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    while( noatual != NULL)    
    {
        printf("ID:%d\n", noatual->id);
        printf("Motorista:%s\n", noatual->motorista);
        printf("Marca:%s\n", noatual->marca);
        printf("Local Atual:%s\n", noatual->la);
        printf("Lista de Destinos:%s\n", noatual->lisd);
        printf("KM/L:%.2f\n", noatual->kml);
        noatual = noatual->prox; 
    }
}



void cad_cam (lcam **cabeca)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    lcam *noatual, *novono;
    int id;
    char mot[200];
    char mar[200];
    char loca[200];
    char lisd[200];
    float kml;

    printf("ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    printf("Motorista:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &mot);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    printf("Marca:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &mar);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    printf("Local Atual:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &loca);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    printf("Lista de Destinos:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &lisd);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    printf("KM/L:\n");
    scanf("%f", &kml);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    if (*cabeca == NULL)   
    {

        (*cabeca) = malloc(sizeof(lcam));
        (*cabeca)->id = id;
        strcpy((*cabeca)->motorista, mot);
        strcpy((*cabeca)->marca, mar);
        strcpy((*cabeca)->la, loca);
        strcpy((*cabeca)->lisd, lisd);
        (*cabeca)->kml = kml;
        (*cabeca)->prox = NULL;
    }
        else{
        noatual = *cabeca;
        while(noatual->prox != NULL){
            noatual = noatual->prox;    
        novono =  malloc(sizeof(lcam));
        novono->id = id;
        strcpy(novono->motorista, mot);
        strcpy(novono->marca,mar);
        strcpy(novono->la,loca);
        strcpy(novono->lisd,lisd);
        novono->kml = kml;
        novono->prox = NULL;
        noatual->prox = novono;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguem,pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está no cadastro de novos caminhões. Quando você cadastra um caminhão que não é o cabeça, você deveria procurar o último caminhão da lista certo? Pois então, ai esta seu erro.

**Seu código errado**

```
else{
    noatual = *cabeca;
    while(noatual->prox != NULL){
        noatual = noatual->prox;    
    novono =  malloc(sizeof(lcam));
    novono->id = id;
    strcpy(novono->motorista, mot);
    strcpy(novono->marca,mar);
    strcpy(novono->la,loca);
    strcpy(novono->lisd,lisd);
    novono->kml = kml;
    novono->prox = NULL;
    noatual->prox = novono;
    }
```

Observe que o seu while está procurando corretamente, entretanto você está fazendo todo o resto a cada iteração.

O correto seria você achar a última posição e só depois executar as outras instruções para encadear na linha. Simplesmente retirando as chaves do **while** resolve teu problema.

**Código correto**

```
else{
    noatual = *cabeca;

    while(noatual->prox != NULL)
        noatual = noatual->prox;

    novono =  malloc(sizeof(lcam));
    novono->id = id;
    strcpy(novono->motorista, mot);
    strcpy(novono->marca,mar);
    strcpy(novono->la,loca);
    strcpy(novono->lisd,lisd);
    novono->kml = kml;
    novono->prox = NULL;
    noatual->prox = novono;
}
```

Assim somente a primeira linha imediatamente abaixo do while será executada nas iterações.

Problema resolvido =)